# MyBatis with upperCase while select and insert

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I would like to insert email address of an user in to Upper case.Is any way we can do it in Mybatis 3.1.x.

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO USERSIGNUP(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,EMAILID, COUNTRY) " +
            "VALUES (#{firstName,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{lastName,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{email.toUpperCase(),jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{countryCode,jdbcType=VARCHAR})")
```

As in above insert I have modified the statement to uppercase but no success

`#{email.toUpperCase()`

any hints.

Answer (score 1):

It worked.

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO USERSIGNUP(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,EMAILID, COUNTRY) " +
            "VALUES (#{firstName,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{lastName,jdbcType=VARCHAR}, UPPER(#{email,jdbcType=VARCHAR}), #{countryCode,jdbcType=VARCHAR})")
```

We have to do like this `UPPER(#{email,jdbcType=VARCHAR})`